# Kindle 4th gen unresponsive for a few minutes

Tags: kindle, hardware

Some time ago, I was reading an e-book on my Kindle 4th gen (the basic one), and after some time (probs over an hour of reading >.<) it wouldn't turn the page or do anything. I don't remember if resetting worked or not, I don't remember what I actually did to solve the problem. It happened again later and that time I just left it for a few minutes (didn't count, maybe 10-15) and did something else. When I looked back it was showing the screen with the tree and the progress bar (I think that meant it was resetting?) and then it started normally. It was a while ago and I forgot to write down what happened, so it's entirely possible that I tried resetting it (by holding the power button, that's the only way I know), it didn't work immediately but did after a while, idk. At least one of the two times, I was reading a commercial Kindle e-book, so I don't think the file is the problem.
That was months ago and I haven't had any issues since.
What could have caused this? Does this mean my Kindle is nearing the end of its life? 
Thank you ^^